# What is Sender Account ID in sqs message attributes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Sqs message attributes contains `Sender Account ID`. But what does it mean?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28603604/amazon-sqs-senderid-inconsitency This question might be give you answer you are looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Amazon SQS SenderId inconsitency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28603604/amazon-sqs-senderid-inconsitency)

Comment: Yes this is duplicate, but the answered question has unclear heading. I think mark current question as duplicate make people easy found when they faced with `Sender Account ID`